# Програма не отображается в консоли Требует Main, а я не знаю куда його вставить. C#

Tags: c#

Программа на с# должна выводить на консоль имя машины и ее силу , но ничего не отображается.
Помогите пофиксить код , пожалуйста
вот мой код

````
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace lab_1_3
{
     class Car
     {
        private string name;
        private double power;

        public void setname(string n)
        {
            name = n;
        }

        public void setpower(double p)
        {
            power = p;
        }

        public void GetCarInfo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name + "  " + power);
        }

        public bool motor()
        {
            if (power == 2.0f & power > 2.0f)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else return false;

        }
    }

    class Program
    {

            static void Car(string[] args)
            {
                Car[] car_array = new Car[30];

                for (int i = 0; i < car_array.Length; i++)
                {
                    car_array[i] = new Car();
                }

                string name;
                for (int i = 0; i < car_array.Length; i++)
                {
                    name = "Car_" + i;
                    car_array[i].setname(name);
                }

                double power;
                for (int i = 0; i < car_array.Length; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write("Enter the power of a motor:  ");
                    power = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                    car_array[i].setpower(power);
                }

                Console.WriteLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Here is the list of the cars:");
                for (int i = 0; i < car_array.Length; i++)
                {
                    car_array[i].GetCarInfo();
                }

                double powerful = 0.0;

                for (int i = 0; i < car_array.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (car_array[i].motor() == true & car_array[i].motor() == true) powerful++;
                }

                Console.WriteLine("The number of powerful cars is" + powerful);

                Console.ReadKey();
            }

    }
}```
````

Comment: В каждую программу есть точка входа, место, откуда начинается выполнение программы. Попробуйте создать новый проект, там будет этот `Main`. А здесь почему-то вы его удалили, или переименовали.

Comment: Не удалили, а переименовали в `static void Car(..`.

Answer (score -1):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace lab_1_3
{
     class Car
     {
        private string name;
        private double power;

        public void setname(string n)
        {
            name = n;
        }

        public void setpower(double p)
        {
            power = p;
        }

        public void GetCarInfo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name + "  " + power);
        }

        public bool motor()
        {
            if (power == 2.0f & power > 2.0f)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else return false;

        }
    }

    class Program
    {

            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Car[] car_array = new Car[30];

                for (int i = 0; i < car_array.Length; i++)
                {
                    car_array[i] = new Car();
                }

                string name;
                for (int i = 0; i < car_array.Length; i++)
                {
                    name = "Car_" + i;
                    car_array[i].setname(name);
                }

                double power;
                for (int i = 0; i < car_array.Length; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write("Enter the power of a motor:  ");
                    power = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                    car_array[i].setpower(power);
                }

                Console.WriteLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Here is the list of the cars:");
                for (int i = 0; i < car_array.Length; i++)
                {
                    car_array[i].GetCarInfo();
                }

                double powerful = 0.0;

                for (int i = 0; i < car_array.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (car_array[i].motor() == true & car_array[i].motor() == true) powerful++;
                }

                Console.WriteLine("The number of powerful cars is" + powerful);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

    }
}
```